# how to extract part of a string matching pattern with separation in r

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to extract part of a file name that matches a set of letters with variable length. The file names consist of several parameters separated by "_", but they vary in the number of parts.  I'm trying to pull some of the parameters out to use separately.

Example file names:

```
a = "Vel_Mag_ft_modelExisting_350cfs_blah3.tif"
b = "Depth_modelDesign_11000cfs_blah2.tif"
```

I'm trying to pull out the parts that start with "model" so I end up with

> "modelExisting"
> "modelDesign"

The filenames are stored as a variable in a data.frame
I've tried

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(files = c(a,b))%>%
  mutate(attempt1 = str_extract(files, "model"),
         attempt2 = str_match(str_split(files, "_"), "model"))
```

but just ended up with the "model" in all cases and not the "model...." that I need.

The pieces I need are a consisent number of pieces from the end, but I couldn't figure out how to specify that either.  I tried

```
str_split(files, "_")[-3]
```

but this threw an error that it must be size 480 or 1 not size 479

Comment: Do you have always digits after the word, then use `sub(".*_([[:alpha:]]+)_\\d+.*", "\\1", a)` and `sub(".*_([[:alpha:]]+)_\\d+.*", "\\1", b)`

Comment: Have you tried `str_extract(files, starts_with("model"))`

Comment: @DohamedDesouky tried, and got an error saying that `starts_with()` only works with selecting function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function to capture the word before the `_` and one or more digits (`\\1`), in the replacement, specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
f1 <- function(x) sub(".*_([[:alpha:]]+)_\\d+.*", "\\1", x)
```

-testing

```
> f1(a)
[1] "modelExisting"
> f1(b)
[1] "modelDesign"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` or `regmatches` like below

```
> s <- c("Vel_Mag_ft_modelExisting_350cfs_blah3.tif", "Depth_modelDesign_11000cfs_blah2.tif")

> lapply(strsplit(s, "_"), function(x) x[which(grepl("^\\d+", x)) - 1])
[[1]]
[1] "modelExisting"

[[2]]
[1] "modelDesign"


> regmatches(s, gregexpr("[[:alpha:]]+(?=_\\d+)", s, perl = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "modelExisting"

[[2]]
[1] "modelDesign"
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use one vs the other?

Comment: @BrianFisher no other reasons indeed, just to show that there are several options to make it :)